# Issues with using np.linalg.solve in Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

Below, I'm trying to code a Crank-Nicholson numerical solution to the Navier-Stokes equation for momentum (simplified with placeholders for time being), but am having issues with solving for umat[timecount,:], and keep getting the error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". I'm extremely new to Python, does anyone know what I could do differently to avoid this problem?

Thanks!!

```
def step(timesteps,dn,dt,Numvpts,Cd,g,alpha,Sl,gamma,theta_L,umat):
    for timecount in range(0, timesteps+1):
        if timecount == 0:
            umat[timecount,:] = 0
        else:
            Km = 1 #placeholder for eddy viscosity
            thetaM = 278.15 #placeholder for theta_m for time being
            A = Km*dt/(2*(dn**2))
            B = (-g*dt/theta_L)*thetaM*np.sin(alpha)
            C = -dt*(1/(2*Sl) + Cd)
            W_arr = np.zeros(Numvpts+1)
            D = np.zeros(Numvpts+1)
            for x in (0,Numvpts): #creating the vertical veocity term
                if x==0:
                    W_arr[x] = 0
                    D[x] = 0
                else:
                    W_arr[x] = W_arr[x-1] - (dn/Sl)*umat[timecount-1,x-1]
                    D = W_arr/(4*dn)
            coef_mat_u = Neumann_mat(Numvpts,D-A,(1+2*A),-(A+D))
            b_arr_u = np.zeros(Numvpts+1) #the array of known quantities
            umat_forward = umat[timecount-1,2:Numvpts]
            umat_center = umat[timecount-1,1:Numvpts-1]
            umat_backward = umat[timecount-1,0:Numvpts-2]

            b_arr_u = np.zeros(Numvpts+1)
            for j in (0,Numvpts):
                if j==0:
                    b_arr_u[j] = 0
                elif j==Numvpts:
                    b_arr_u[j] = 0
                else:
                    b_arr_u[j] = (A+D[j])*umat_backward[j]*(1-2*A)*umat_center[j] + (A-D[j])*umat_forward[j] - C*(umat_center[j]*umat_center[j]) - B

            umat[timecount,:] = np.linalg.solve(coef_mat_u,b_arr_u) 
    return(umat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that,

```
for i in (0, 20):
    print(i),
```

will give result `0 20` not `0 1 2 3 4 ... 20`

So you have to use the `range()` function

```
for i in range(0, 20 + 1):
    print(i),
```

to get `0 1 2 3 4 ... 20`

I have not gone through your code rigorously, but I think the problem is in your two inner `for` loops:

```
    for x in (0,Numvpts): #creating the vertical veocity term
```

which is setting values only at `zero` th and `(Numvpts-1)` th index. I think you must use

```
    for x in range(0,Numvpts):
```

Similar is the case in (`range()` must be used):

```
    for j in (0,Numvpts):
```

Also, here `j` never becomes `== Numvpts`, but you are checking the condition? I guess it must be `== Numvpts-1`

And also the `else` condition is called for every index other than `0`? So in your code the right hand side vector has same numbers from  index 1 onwards!

I think the fundamental problem is that you are not using `range()`. Also it is a good idea to solve the NS eqns for a small grid and manually check the A and b matrix to see whether they are being set correctly.